# Do I need to use a block or form to implement login box, or can I just post to a 'login' url the user details?

Tags: 6, users

I have static HTML for a login box which contains a form with username and password inputs and is part of the site header, which will be on every page ie. this is not a login 'page'.

To integrate this with the Drupal login system, can I point the form action at a certain url to post the login details and perform the login? Thereby, not requiring any Drupal backend form/block/theme coding?

Or do I need to implement my own form, or customise an existing form to achieve this? If so, why is that? What do I need from the Drupal back end to successfully login ie. hidden form fields that need to be passed with the login details etc?

I am trying to implement the site in the cleanest way possible, using my own HTML 5/ CSS 3 markup, so overriding most html so that the tonne of classes Drupal adds, and the extra unnecessary markup are scraped. So, ideally I would like to avoid having to make a login form/block as part of the back end.

Answer (score 0):

You can print login block in the tpl file. No need to use username/password fields of HTML/CSS.

```
<?php print drupal_get_form('user_login_block'); ?>
```

For Registration :

```
<?php print drupal_get_form('user_register_form'); ?>
```

Comment: I want to use my own HTML/CSS because it is much better than Drupal markup. I am asking can I just submit the form variable to a url to successfully login?

Comment: but you can theme login form of drupal accordingly. It is the good practice.

Comment: Why? Where does the login form post to? I want to know why I should/need to use the Drupal login form?

Comment: because of security .. you cant submit a login form correctly if you dont use $form['form_build_id']['#id'].

Answer (score 0):

You can theme your login form using **hook_theme** in your **template.php**

```
function THEMENAME_theme(){
  return array(
  'user_login_block' => array(
      'arguments' => array('form' => NULL),
      'template' => 'user-login-block',
    ),
}
```

now create **user-login-block.tpl.php** in your theme. You can use your html and drupal_render($form[ELEMENTS]) in that tpl file.

**For example**

```
<ul>
      <li>
        <label>Username</label>
        <span class="login_field_box">
        <?php  
           $form['name']['#description']='';
           print drupal_render($form['name']);
        ?>
        </span> 
      </li>
      <li>
        <label>Password</label>
        <span class="login_field_box">
        <?php print drupal_render($form['pass']);?>
        </span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <?php  
            $form['submit']['#attributes']['class']=array('Login');
            print drupal_render($form['submit']);
        ?> 
      </li>
    </ul>

    <div style="display:none"><?php echo drupal_render($form) ?></div> <!--this must be in your tpl at end-->
```

Comment: I have seen examples like this. What do the drupal_render functions render? Where does this post the details to? I'd rather just post myself than use Drupal. Or is there a reason I NEED to do this?

Comment: `http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_render/6` mostly used to print form and form elements.